# What kind of brain mushroom is this?

Tags: identification, mushrooms

I found this (brain?) mushroom near the wall of a building under the roof. The soil seemed very dry. (Northern Germany presumably)
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: .is there a dead elm around, and is it hallow, because it looks like a morel

Comment: This was taken a while ago so I can't really say for sure but that might have been the case.

Comment: there's no way to know for sure unless you can do things like get a spore print, or cut it open, and look at the bore surface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly looks like a Morel type; However , in the US there are also false Morels which are not edible . It seems like the right time of year; Do local oaks have small fuzzy new leaves ? If you like mushrooms , it would be worth identifying properly because the are likely to come up the same place ,the same time next year.